# I want to get the updated Salary by EmpID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column EmpID and Salary. I want to get the updated salary each EmpID.

FIGURE 1 :

| ID | EMPID | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00000 | 75000 |
| 2 | 00000 | 80000 |
| 3 | 00001 | 75000 |
| 4 | 00001 | 90000 |
| 5 | 00001 | 91000 |
| 6 | 00010 | 50000 |
| 7 | 00010 | 60000 |
| 8 | 00010 | 70000 |

This is my initial query that I created with specific EMPID 00000 :

```
Select DISTINCT EmpID,Salary from Table1 as t1 WHERE  Salary != '0.00' AND EXISTS 
 (SELECT TOP 1 Salary ,EmpID From Table1 where Table1.EmpID = t1 ORDER BY ID DESC) AND EmpID = '00000'
```

The output that I get is still the same as Figure 1.

The output must be in distinct in EmpID with the updated salary.

```
/****** Sub query example  ******/
/****** This is the output I would like to display  ******/
Select TOP 1 Salary FROM Table1 Where EMPID = '00000' ORDER BY ID DESC
Select TOP 1 Salary FROM Table1 Where EMPID = '00001' ORDER BY ID DESC
Select TOP 1 Salary FROM Table1 Where EMPID = '00010' ORDER BY ID DESC
```

FIGURE 2 :

| ID | EMPID | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00000 | 80000 |
| 2 | 00001 | 91000 |
| 3 | 00010 | 70000 |

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what are you looking for can be achieved by group by as follows, however chosing your desired ID remain issue but it has been acheived by `row_number`

```
SELECT Row_number()
         OVER (
           ORDER BY empid) AS ID,
       empid,
       Max(salary)         Salary
FROM   table1
GROUP  BY empid
```

in addition you can use `Row_number` and `Sub-query` in order to distinguish new changes.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmpID) AS ID,EmpID, Salary
FROM   (SELECT ID,
               empid,
               salary,
               Row_number()
                 OVER (
                   partition BY empid
                   ORDER BY salary DESC) AS RowNumber
        FROM   table1) T
WHERE  rownumber = 1
```

Comment: A good answer explains what is happening in addition to having working code.

Comment: Thank you its working fine. I learned something new today. I should study more.

Comment: your desired ID is not in accordance with ID in table,I used row_number to produce your desired ID, happy to help